# Is there any documentation on System.CalloutException: public0-proxy1-0-ia4.data.sfdc.net

Tags: callout

During integration testing in a sandbox, an Http callout failed with what looks like an internal Salesforce issue:

> System.CalloutException: public0-proxy1-0-ia4.data.sfdc.net

I cannot find it documented anywhere.  It certainly seems like an internal proxy error, but I'm surprised it surfaced in Apex.  The test endpoint unexpectedly had many more files to fetch than expected, and the process under test fetches the file, processes it, and enqueues itself to process the next file.  This led to many more callouts than planned, although only 2 or 3 per Apex transaction.  I'm not aware of any per-day callout limits, but since this is a sandbox, I considered that it could be a factor.  Is anything known about this issue?

Update:  I was able to resume integration testing with no further issues, so it certainly wasn't a daily limit.  Would still like to find some documentation, known issue, etc., so that we can code for it and retry if needed.